# Как правильно работать с индексами MySQL

Tags: база-данных, индексы, mysql

Есть у меня запрос, где:

```
WHERE `id` = 1 AND `success` = 0 AND `del` = 0
```

Как понять, где ставить индексы(обычные или составные)?

Comment: Индексы нужны для оптимизатора MySQL. Как Вы хотите использовать их в SQL запросе? Они выставляются на этапе проектирования / создания таблиц.

Comment: @GenchiK, возможно я криво объяснил) Вообщем как мне знать, на какие поля ставить индексы(обычные или составные) в самой базе.

Comment: Выставляете кол-во символов по которым будут индексироваться поля. Поля типов: varchar, text, int (если это действительно большие числа ). Индексы, в основном, выставляются на те поля, где много данных. Если использовать индексы неразумно, то это только замедлит SQL запросы, поэтому ставим их там, где это действительно нужно. А вобще советую почитать про индексы в документации MySQL. В любом случае Вам это нужно, раз затронули тему.

Comment: @GenchiK, int(11) это большое число считается? Индекс нужен?

Comment: если оно (поле) будет иметь длину 11 символов, но разные значения, то да. Ведь объявление int(11) не значит что там будет стабильно 11 символов, может быть и меньше. К примеру ID. Он начинается с 1 и в плюс бесконечность. Тогда не стоит. А вот unix time stamp - строка из 11 символов, но с разными значениями, тогда стоит. Ещё один момент, индексы добавляются, для того чтобы быстрее сортировать и находить инфу. Если вы не будете по целочисленному типу сортировать или проводить поиск, то не стоит использовать индекс.

Comment: С каких это пор на ID индекс не ставят? На него в первую очередь, т.к. через него обычно записи связываются.

Ставить надо на тех полях, по которым поиск идет чаще всего.

В остальных случаях смотреть и пробовать. EXPLAIN может многое сказать, но он только подсказывает, не всегда правильно. Смотреть в каждом случае самому.

Если поле участвует только в одном редком запросе и этот запрос не критичен - то зачем на этом поле индекс? Если запрос критичен (по времени), и индекс ускорит выборку - то почему бы и нет?

Правда не стоит забывать, что индексы замедляют вставку/обновление.

Comment: По этому примеру:

    WHERE `id` = 1 AND `success` = 0 AND `del` = 0

Трудно что-то сказать конкретное, т.к. кроме этого запроса есть еще куча других, в которых эти поля либо могут быть, либо не могут.

Что точно - это ID. Обязательно. PRIMARY KEY.

`success` и `del` - не меняются часто, так что тоже можно. Если они участвуют вместе (т.е. `success` = 0 AND `del` = 0), то можно повесить один индекс на два поля, иначе - по каждому полю свой индекс.

Про индексы - лучше читать, т.к. по одному запросу ничего толком не скажешь, надо смотреть на все. Кроме вас никто лучше не скажет)

Comment: Друзья, посмотрите на этот конкретный запрос. Тут же в лоб идет выборка по первичному ключу. Зачем еще какие-то индексы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для данного запроса просится составной индекс. 
В "success"  и "del" я так понимаю, возможны только значения 0 и 1 ?
А вообще, решение о необходимости индексов должно приниматься на этапе создания таблицы.

Comment: Совсем не так. Индексы нужно выбирать на конкретных данных, смотреть explain и использовать бенчмарки. А здесь всё ещё проще. Достаточно primary key.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае, достаточно оставить единственный индекс primary key. Т.к в первом же условии видно, что выборка происходит по уникальному полю id.

Даже если бы выборка шла по какому-то другому условию, скорее всего, индексы для полей success и del не понадобятся. Вероятно, эти поля принимают значения 0 или 1, т.о селективность у этих столбцов будет низкая и строить индекс по ним было бы излишним.